# How to override the document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, monk

I have mongodb collection with below document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5652f7e1a9fddf438369c866"),
    "USER_ID" : "Vinsy",
    "USER_NAME" : "Vinsy",
    "FIRST_NAME" : "XYZxx",
    "LAST_NAME" : "ABC",
    "CONTACTS"  :[]
}
```

I am trying to update the document with below query

```
collection.update({
        USER_ID: req.body.USER_ID
    },{
        "USER_ID" : "Vinsy",
        "USER_NAME" : "Vinsy",
        "FIRST_NAME" : "XYZxx",
        "LAST_NAME" : "ABC",
    }, function(error, data) {

        try {
            if (data) {
                res.json("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                res.json("FAILURE" + error);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            res.json("FAILURE" + e);
        }
    });
```

The query is updating the document but it's removing CONTACTS. How to keep it as it is? really appreciate you help.

Comment: can we use $set  with upsert:true

Comment: Yes, you can use `$set` in upserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `$set` operator. The `$set` operator instructs MongoDB that you want to update specific fields in a document rather than overwriting it with a new document.

```
collection.update({
        USER_ID: req.body.USER_ID
   },
   { $set:
     {
       "USER_ID" : "Vinsy",
       "USER_NAME" : "Vinsy",
       "FIRST_NAME" : "XYZxx",
       "LAST_NAME" : "ABC",
     }
   }
```

Comment: it won't remove my CONTACTS field?

Comment: If you use `$set` the CONTACTS field will not be removed

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.update({USER_ID: req.body.USER_ID}, {$set: {"USER_ID": "Vinsy","USER_NAME": "Vinsy","FIRST_NAME": "XYZxx","LAST_NAME": "ABC"}}, function (error, data) {
    try {
        if (data) {
            res.json("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            res.json("FAILURE" + error);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.json("FAILURE" + e);
    }
});
```